# Reusing encrypted message on MITM attack?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis

I'm using RSA public key private key for sending AES key from each client to server application.
then i'm using this AES key and IV for communicating between client and server.

what should i do for this MITM attack scenario??

client[encrypted text]   ---> Server

**the MITM can use this encrypted text again to send it to server**. consider if this encrypted text is an operation on transfering money.

the solutions i have planned for this are these:

1- attach new IV(encrypted) on each sending to server , so the server knows what's the next message iv is

well , i just can think about this only for now

Comment: Search for replay attack counter measures...

Comment: well, thanks. wikipedia says that we should use a new session key on each message sending. something like new IV I'v mentioned about it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the mode of encryption used.
If you are using CBC, predictable IVs maybe an issue.
I would recommend not reusing IV to prevent message replay. You can add a counter inside the encrypted payload and ensure it is increasing.
Notice when you add protection against replay you need to think about out of order etc.
In many cases protocols add timestamps and allow only a limited discrepancy.

Comment: i actually was looking for something like telegram protocol, https://core.telegram.org/mtproto. thanks anyway

Comment: using a well defined protocol like Mtproto or signals is definetly better then invenying your own. Though you didn't clarify your use case enough to suggest an off the self solution. the two protocols mentioned are for messaging if you have just a single server with known public key you may want something else.

Comment: well i'm trying to create a game server. so i need an authentication system. i have implemented public key private key in server and client. but i want to reduce the possibility of MITM attack.you mentioned about CBC mode of Aes. what is wrong with CBC? i have used Cryptool application from this domain https://www.cryptool.org/en/. and according to this reference, AES with CBC mode would take more than 1 galaxy time to decrypt.

Comment: CBC if fine when used properly. Except. It does not provide authentication only encryption it is malleable an attacker can modify the messages (without discovering their content). And it requires non predictable IVs for each message. I normally recommend GCM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode but we are diverging. This requires non repeating IVs non, being predictable is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution that i figured it out is this:

1- Client: capture the current time(including melee seconds) and send it to server
2- Server: use this time as a counter
3- Server: saves last e.g. 50 records of these counters
4- Server: if a message received and the time was used in the record drop it
5- Server: if a message received and the time was passed after the threshold (which is impossible. because you can't catch the time :) , just kidding ), then drop it
6- Server: if a message received with a time of future (i mean you must be kidding me. unless someone create a time travel machine!), then drop it
7- 5th and 6th numbers should be check with "**OR**" operator.

the 4th,5th and 6th elements are for preventing message replay attack.

The **AES** keys are created from client side and encrypted using server public key (**RSA**) with a created time. so this will authenticate the client.

https://cdn3.bbcode0.com/uploads/2020/10/5/3972534b817d44957d5af877aa1ce81b-full.png

Did i missed something?? :(